# Is there another way to call Base method from derived which is virtual

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there is another way to call the virtual base method from derived instead of:

```
void Y() //is virtual in base
{
   Base::Y();
}
```

If this is a duplicate, I'm sorry.

Comment: Why are you looking for another way if you already have something that works? What would that other way need to add?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Because its always nice to learn more and see different solutions to solve 1 problem

Comment: Yes but it's also completely infeasible unless you have a clear set of requirements. In short, you haven't told us what the "problem" is. Without constraints, it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: First you say `call the virtual base method from derived`, then you say `call Y from the base outside of the derived class`. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of **why** you want to do this, you can achieve the same thing using this alternate syntax. You simply add some resolution syntax to the dereferencing of the variable (the same can be achieved with non-pointers dereferenced by the `.` operator)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    virtual void X( )
    {
        cout << "A::X()\n";
    }

    virtual void Y( )
    {
        cout << "A::Y()\n";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void X( )
    {
        cout << "B::X()\n";
    }

    virtual void Y( )
    {
        cout << "B::Y()\n";
    }
};

void main( )
{
    B* xb = new B( );

    A* xa = xb;

    xb->X( );
    xb->Y( );

    xa->X( );
    xa->Y( );

    xb->A::X( );
    xb->A::Y( );

    system( "PAUSE" );
}
```

Comment: Dude this is nice. I didn't actually know you could do ptr->CLASS::METHOD(). Cheers that was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: `void main( )` and `system( "PAUSE" );`?

Comment: Haha, I beg pardon on grounds that it is irrelevant to the answer.